# CodeIgniter using if to show some table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, if-statement

So i am trying to make a website for collecting data from user and classify the data as 'suspicious' or 'not suspicious'. After i collect and classify the data, i want to show and send to server ONLY 'suspicious' data.

My table has one column called 'note', where the value of the 'note' is 'suspicious' or 'not suspicious'

is it possible to show the part of table that only have 'not suspicious' value in 'note' ? if possible, can you guys give me any idea how ?

Here is my code for showing the data:

Controller:

```php
public function success() {
  $dataz['resultss'] = $this->welcome_model->dataz(); 
  $this->load->view('success',$dataz);
}
```

Model

```php
public function dataz() {
  $query = $this->db->get('info');
  $results = $query->result();  
  return $resultss;
}
```

View

```php
<?php
  foreach($resultss as $row) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$row->name.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row->note.'</td>';                  
?>
  <td>
  </td>
<?php
    echo '</tr>';
  }
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You have a spelling mistake here `return $resultss;` in model function should be return $results not sure if any cause of it

Comment: oh i did it on purpose, i have another var $results for different data

Comment: The return should match `$results = $query->result(); return $results`

Comment: what is the dataType of 'note' field in your database? @MikaelLouis

Comment: yes i was wrong, i did this: $resultss = $query->result(); 
         return $resultss; 

and now it works, thankyou guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve your objective in many ways.

For 'not suspicious' records, use this,

```
 $query = $this->db->get_where('info', array('note' => 'not suspicious'));
```

For 'suspicious' records, use this,

```
 $query = $this->db->get_where('info', array('note' => 'suspicious'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The method @Naga suggested is better but if you want to stick to your way and do it in view;

```
<?php
  foreach($resultss as $row) {
    if($row->note == 'not suspicious') {
       echo '<tr>';
       echo '<td>'.$row->name.'</td>';
       echo '<td>'.$row->note.'</td>';                  
       echo '<td></td>'; // why this extra td?
       echo '</tr>';
    }
  }
?>
```